# How to standarize feature vector with data in different scales?

Tags: neural-network, data-mining, feature-engineering, normalization, feature-scaling

Let's suppose I have a dataset with numerical attributes of different types.

Let's suppose I want to employ a Neural Network for supervised classification with that dataset. For that, I need to extract feature vectors from that data.

Those feature vectors must be suitable for NNs. (should be normalized/standarized vectors...)

> As an example, our dataset consist of data from football games.

**DATASET:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| local_elo| vis_elo| local_pts | vis_pts | loc_goals | vis_goals |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2820   |  3250  |     45    |    54   |    13     |     17    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|   4230   |  5125  |     87    |    81   |    67     |     65    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The feature vectors this two data points:

```
x_1 = [2820, 3250, 45, 54, 13, 17]
x_2 = [4230, 5125, 87, 81, 67, 65]
```

but they are not suitable for feed them into a Neural Network.

How could this dataset be preprocessed in order to extract feature vectors suitables for feeding them into a Neural Network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use function preprocessing.scale from sklearn

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np
X_train = np.array([[ 1., -1.,  2.],
                    [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  1., -1.]])
X_scaled = preprocessing.scale(X_train)
```

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html

Answer (score 2):

we've to use standardization(substitute by z-scores or subtract mean divide by standard deviation) in such cases:

```
#find mean of each feature    
mean = data.mean(axis = 0)
#subtract mean
data - = mean
#find standard deviation of each feature
std = data.std(axis = 0)
#divide by it
data /= std
```